# configure SublimeLinter-jshint to work with node in Sublime3

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3, jshint

So according to what I understand to doc, this is the way to do it.
Sublime > preferences > user settings:

```
{
    "linters": {
        "jshint": {
            "node": true
        }
    }
}
```

it is not working.
I'm using sublime3 and sublimelinter with sublimelinter-jshint.
also I have jshint installed in my local enviroment.

any help ?

Comment: There shouldn't need to be any settings updated, I've got that working here locally and haven't edited any settings.  Do you have `jshint` available from the `PATH`?  Also you may need to restart sublime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doesn't belong in `Preferences -> Settings-User`. Instead, open `Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeLinter -> Settings-User` and add the following after the line `"linters": {`

```json
            "jshint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "node": true
            },
```

You can delete the final comma `,` after the closing brace `}` if there are no other entries in the `linters` array.

Comment: I can not get this option to work using the settings-file. The only way the "node" option works for me is by adding `/* jshint node: true */` at the top of a .js file. Any idas why it does not work?